# Do trailing zeroes after the radix point matter in binary?

Tags: binary

In decimal I can discard zeros after the radix point, e.g.:
$$ 0.250_{10} = 0.25_{10} $$
It seems to me that I can do the same with binary:
$$ 0.10_2 = 0.1_2 $$
Because

$$ 1\times\frac{1}{2}+0\times\frac{1}{4} = 1\times\frac{1}{2} $$
Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: it's the same in any base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's exactly the same system. The only restriction on decimal relative to binary is no digits 2-9. As per your proof, removing a trailing zero is always equivalent to subtracting zero and therefore has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

While Roberts Frost's answer is perfectly correct there is however one small catch!

When engaged in practical computations which seek to obtain an approximation $A$ to the solution $T$ of a complicated equation, then there is a profound difference between the statement $T \approx 1$ and the statement $T \approx 1.0$. In the first case, we implicitly state the error $E = T-A$ satisfies $|E| \leq 5\times10^{-1}$. In the second case, we implicitly make the stronger statement that $|E| \leq 5 \times 10^{-2}$.

By dropping the "extra" 0 we are selling ourselves short because we give the wrong impression of the quality of the approximation.

Comment: **tl;dr** no difference b/w 0.1 and 0.10 because of the base, but difference there is a difference in [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). (Though that's not something that the body of the question asks, but it's important to note given the current title)

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha: Your edits are not visible to others until approved. I answered the question 60 minutes ago. I made an edit 54 minutes ago. You made an edit to the question which changed the title and became visible to all others 43 minutes ago.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha: There is no decimal point in a binary number. It is called the binary point. In general we speak of the radix point. I would not have approved the new title.

Comment: Oh. My bad. I'll edit it to say radix point